# Identifying the source of execution

Tags: c#, asp.net

Imagine I have a class in C# called "Bar" that has a public function on it called Foo().

Inside the Foo() function, is there a way for me to to identify where Foo() has been executed from?  More precisely I want to find out if Foo() was called from an .aspx file.  Like this <% Bar.Foo() %>  versus from code behind  Bar.Foo().

The reason I ask is that I want the function to behave differently when it is executed inside a .aspx file.

**EDIT:**

I realize I can use two different functions, I really don't want to get into the boring details of my problem because it is very difficult to explain, not to mention very long.  Just know that it is a unique problem I am wrestling with, and I know I can solve it by being able to identify the source of where it is called.

Comment: Why don't you simply use two different functions for this task (or an argument to distinguish between the two)?

Comment: Well I realize I can use two different functions, but I really don't want to get into the long details of my problem.  But I know I can solve my problem by identifying the source of where it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "behave differently"; I wonder whether checking [`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) (after adding a reference to `System.Web.dll`) would be a better idea...

Otherwise, you're into stack-frame parsing territory; not a good idea.

Of course, I'd want the code to do the same job either way, using something like dependency injection to handle the differences...

Comment: I don't know if the context will be of any value.  It will show you the request, but I don't know if what stage of the pipeline the request is in.

Comment: One reason that stack frame parsing is a bad idea is that it is VERY slow.

Comment: Actually, IMO a better reason is that it is **brittle**; you refactor? boom, you broke it. JIT decides to inline a method? boom, it broke.

Comment: @Marc - I see, but he wants it to work differently in code behind vs. mark up.  I think the context will still be there when the page is rendered (though I haven't checked).   I could see this to differentiate between a console app and web app, but not during PreRender vs. the markup.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible by examining the stack, but to me that would be a very bad smell.  You might want to use the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern to modify the behavior of Bar, giving it a different Foo() implementation when called from a web page.

For example,

```
<% new WebBar( Bar ).Foo(); %>
```

Where WebBar has a different implementation of Foo that uses Bar, but does the different computation that you desire.  This keeps your Bar class from having to be "web-aware", but still gives you a relatively easy way to get your "web" behavior from it.

On the other hand, if what you are after is just having it return a string when executed in code-behind and write to the response when executed in ASPX, then just use a different set of tags.

```
<%= Bar.Foo() %>
```

instead of

```
<% Bar.Foo(); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, an ASPX file is actually converted to the same file as your .cs and designer.cs file at compile-time.  They are all really abstractions of a single run-time class.  I think what you're trying to do is format them differently if they are being displayed.  I recommend you consider creating a function for that or overiding the ToString if it's a class.